# To use CSV or XML for data imports?

Tags: php, xml, csv, tabular

I'm writing a script were I want to be able to import data into a database table. The table is either mysql, SQLite 3, or PostgreSQL. Hypothetically, it could be a lot of data (the data is products/categories/descriptions etc for e-commerce software).

What's the best (fastest and more universally used) format to hold such data in? And what is the best way to import the data?

I've done some research, but it just made the question harder imo. For example, some say that csv is better because it's smaller, some say xml is worse because there isn't one standard.. some say xml is better because the data is easier to handle.

Thoughts? I'm open to other formats as well. And the software is written in php if that makes a difference.

Comment: I've never heard of a way to tell MySQL to import XML. But everybody understands CSV. Seems like CSV is the no-brainer here.

Comment: Well it's a matter of personal preference, it would basically depend on what you would want to with the data. Can you specify anything?

Comment: There isn't really a single standard for CSV either. I've seen many different flavors in the wild (and things get tricky if you data has internal line breaks).

Comment: I know there isn't a standard for csv either really (though it is named comma separated value), but it seems easy enough to pass which delimiter is being used etc. to a function. That's why I see it as easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CSV and XML have different purposes :

- for storing raw tables data, csv is a quite exact representation of a table (that's it : columns and rows). So it is easy to manipulate, but does not allow you to reproduce relationships, which might be a problem if data consistency is a requirement
- for serializing entities orobjects, XML is the way to go : it offers a tree structure and is quite readable. and XML has some advantages : you can use DTDs or XSDs for validating data, it's tree structure can be used to maintain data consistency...

Latest versions of mysql support XML importing : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

Answer (score 7):

I've almost always used CSV for storing data outside of SQL. The only real complication it adds is remembering to escape everything properly!

Additional bonus is that most spreadsheet software can read it just fine.

Comment: +1 for most spreadsheet software. At least upto 2002 XML was largely unsupported.

Comment: Just use a decent library to create the CSV; don't try to build it by hand with strings.

Comment: On the topic of spreadsheet software opening csv, OpenOffice has no problem opening it directly. Excel for Mac really doesn't want to open it though. It can import the data without a problem, but no luck opening and saving. Any thoughts from anyone on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be best to take advantage of each database export/import features and use the recommended format for them. For example, for MySQL you can use [LOAD DATE INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

"The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed. The file name must be given as a literal string. "

And yes, if you need one format, i would also suggest CSV, as i used it and is very portable and easy to alter and to read, and also agree with @Chris G.

Comment: I would disagree in saying that a CSV file is easy to read: I find it very difficult to visually connect values with their headers—unless you use software like Excel to view it [CAVEAT: If you have a date in your CSV file, Excel **will** change it's format to one that has a comma in it, which will produce errors from `LOAD`]. However, I would agree that CSV is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome to my thoughts. I spent the best part of 2 days reading the .NET literature on XML serialization. I thought it would be more readable and the experience stand me in good stead, particularly with reference to SOAP. If you have a lot of data it would definitely be more readable than CSV. Maybe it's me, .NET, or my XML Schema definition (or desire?) but I'm regretting not writing the XML out with the standard stream/serialization mechanism and foregoing the framework's extra functionality. All I learnt over the past 2 days was XML Schema and some .NET framework that I can't control yet.

You do have added type safety with XML, but I would question whether it is flexible with regard to defaults for unsupplied elements

Answer (score 0):

You answered yourself for the mostpart. All of the approaches have it's pros and cons.

I have one recommendation above all, try to create an API in your application that will let you easily change the formats you supply. If you've got some experience with MVC architectures, think about the XML or CSV output as a mere view. If you create an interface which will easily let you fill in another template, you'll be more flexible in situations where you require another format.

In the end, handling both formats will be very similar. Handling standardized XML requires more practice and can be tricky at times. For example using a standard like [UBL 2.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.0/UBL-2.0.html) (something I've seen pretty common in e-commerce solutions) will give you a robust solution but it is a headache to extend it, unless you're skilled in XML and its schemas. However you'll be speaking with a documented language.

If you choose an arbitrary format/layout of the export you define and customers/supplier/any other third party will have to implement it, it really doesn't matter what you choose, the time required to parse or build them is roughly the same.

Comment: What do you mean an API? When it does the restore, it just calls the restore() function. And I'm hoping I can edit that in the future to check if $_FILES[$file] is a zip of the csv files or an xml. But right now, only one is important. Is that what you mean my using an API?

Answer (score 0):

csv is easier to use while xml is fancier and from my point of view carries more overhead

Answer (score 0):

Although unconventional, I would use JSON - somehting like this...

```
// select your data
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM some_table;");

// build an associative array for each row, and add to total data
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $rows[] = $row;
}

// encode it all as JSON
$data = json_encode( $rows );
```

Which has the advantage that the data is stored as a very easily manipulated object (`$rows` in my example) in php before it is encoded, and can be passed to almost any language for further processing.

If you are worried about the size of the data, then you can comprress it, as it is repetative, it compresses very well.

This method handles all escaping, and provides a way to encode/decode data without building custom functions for re-attaching column headers etc...

It is not the most efficient method, and does not produce the most condensed format, but it is highly portable, and allows for very easy processing... like this:

```
  // convert JSON string into php object
  // then loop over it to operate on each row
  foreach(json_decode($data) as $row){
    // create empty array for keys and vals
    $vals = $keys = array();
    // create array of keys and vals in the data row
    foreach($row as $k => $v){
      $keys[] = $k; $vals[] = $v;
    }
    // build an insert statement using the keys and values from each row
    echo "INSERT INTO some_table (".implode(',',$keys).") VALUES (".implode(',',$vals).");\n";   
  }
```

Although it is not the most efficient, I like this way of working with data, and I feel it is less error prone as the structure of the data and the data are never seperated.

I doubt many people will agree with this as the overhead of encoding and decoding JSON means it will perform poorly compared with CSV for example, although probably better than the beast that is XML.